# Anzahl Morpheme im Deutschen

Tags: morphology

Gibt es Schätzungen, wieviele Morpheme es im Deutschen gibt? Die Zahl der (bekannten) Worte geht wohl in die Hunderttausende (ohne künftige Neologismen), wenn man auch noch gebeugte Formen als eigene Worte betrachtet, eher in die Millionen. Gibt es eher Tausende oder Zehntausende Morpheme?

Answer (score 2):

My own guess is about 10000.

That because the information density is about the same per time in all natural languages, languages with mostly ideal syllables are spoken about twice as fast per syllable as German is spoken, and there are about 100 ideal syllables.

That leads me to the conclusion there should be about 100·100 syllables in German.

Comment: Great back-of-the-envelope guess!

Comment: But at second reading I don't quite get it. Please clarify. Where does the second factor 100 come from?

Comment: Languages as Spanish or Japanese are having mostly ideal syllables, about 100 different ones each. And they are spoken twice as fast as German. So they get to 100·100 = 10000 combinations of two Spanish or Japanese syllables at their normal speed in the same time you speak one German syllable at your normal speed. And as the information density is roughly the same, that means there must be about 10000 different German syllables.